# How to display tooltip or hint similar to Delphi XE tooltip code insight

Tags: delphi, components, tooltip

I'm looking at wanting to implement a tooltip similar to the way Delphi XE does when you're debugging and you hover over an object.  ie, it opens up a hint window with + signs which you can expand etc.

I'm trying to create a hint window which will show a list of items (for example) when hovering over a control (such as a button) which will let the user click on an item and I can then do something based on the item they've selected.

Are there any components out there that might do that already?  Or am I better of just creating a borderless form and handle the showing/hiding myself with mouse events?

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 2):

I know there are hint components **with embedded html**. So you can have a kind of html treeview inside you hint!
I think it is a solution for you.

- [HTMLHint](http://www.torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=187) from TMS Software
- [THintBox](http://www.torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=1928) from Cramon Utilities (freeware!)

Comment: A quick look at HTMLHint (better obtained from the author: http://tmssoftware.com/site/htmlhint.asp), does not show me a readily available way to respond to clicks on the hint window let alone to respond according to what was clicked. Don't know HintBox, but my guess would be it doesn't either, as most hint components do not provide this behaviour, which is what Jason is looking for.

Comment: @Marjan Venema: Yeah, I have no experience with these components. It heavily depends on what Jason want to do in the click event. If it is as Delphi IDE, so embedded HTML technic may be sufficient. Do you agree ?

Comment: My point was that there is no "on click event" in the THTMLHint component. While THTMLHint supports the embedded mini HTML, unlike other TMS components that support the mini HTML, THTMLHint does not have any of the OnAnchor... events to respond to mouse clicks on an anchor tag.

Comment: Thanks all, but in the end I will just create a form and do all necessary processing myself.  It was quite easy to do - bit of fun getting the form to not lose focus (or at least appear to not lose focus) when clicking on my "hint" form, but all good.  Using forms will give me plenty of flexibility too.

Comment: @Jason: Thx for the feedback ! it's always good to know the end of the story.

Comment: I would simply suggest create a window of your own using CreateWindow, the custom window you created to the activation, deactivation of the hints. Place TWebBrowser in the custom hint and process OnBeforeNavigate2. A very good start would be to read the source code of Th and understand how THintWindow and THintWindowClass works in Delphi.